# Release of Dji Windows SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

Is there any update on the release date of the Dji Windows SDK?
Will it support to connect to Mavic Air via Remote Controller/USB (instead via Wifi)?
Will it support waypoints?

Thanks for any infos/ updates!

Answer (score 0):

the public beta 0.1.0 is now available on https://developer.dji.com/windows-sdk/support/ and https://github.com/dji-sdk

Mavic Air via Remote Controller is still not supported, but waypoints are supported now!

You can find the API reference via https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/windows-api/SDKManager/DJISDKManager.html

Best regards, Marcel